# Выведение autocomplete из PHP + sql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

Есть PHP обработчик search.php:

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','***','***','***') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT prefix_shop.name1 AS name, prefix_images.name AS img FROM prefix_shop JOIN prefix_images ON (prefix_shop.id = prefix_images.element_id) WHERE prefix_images.module_name like 'shop' AND name like '%$my_data%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['name']."\n";
        }
    } 
?>
```

при `sql` запросе:

```
SELECT prefix_shop.name1 AS name, prefix_images.name AS img FROM prefix_shop JOIN prefix_images ON (prefix_shop.id = prefix_images.element_id) WHERE prefix_images.module_name like 'shop';
```

получаю таблицу с 2 столбцами:
[image: таблица]

так же есть скрипт `autocomplete`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("search.php", {
 selectFirst: true
    });
});
</script>
```

я знаю что я могу вызвать частичный адрес путем

```
echo $row['img'];
```

но мне нужно что бы при совпадении `%$my_data%` выводилось из `name` и рядом попадало `<img scr="http://site.com/img/'.$row['img'].'">`

```
echo $row['name']."<img scr="http://site.com/img/'.$row['img'].'">\n";
```

как то так должно получиться, но довести до ума не могу

**UPDATE**

Забыл добавить что есть еще такой js код:

```
jQuery.extend({
    queue: function( elem, type, data ) {
        if ( !elem ) {
            return;
        }

        type = (type || "fx") + "queue";
        var q = jQuery.data( elem, type );

        // Speed up dequeue by getting out quickly if this is just a lookup
        if ( !data ) {
            return q || [];
        }

        if ( !q || jQuery.isArray(data) ) {
            q = jQuery.data( elem, type, jQuery.makeArray(data) );

        } else {
            q.push( data );
        }

        return q;
    },
```

Comment: Алексей, я не совсем понимаю, что надо... Если есть `q` - показывать только `name`, а если его нет - показывать и `name` и картинку?

Comment: нет нужно в `q` записать то что в `name` и то что с ней рядом в `img`, но ваша формулировка вопроса тоже подает, результат желательно иметь именно вами описанный.

Comment: все равно путаюсь... Значит `search.php` должен выдавать содержимое выпадающего `autocomplete`. Так? В нем, в этом списке, должны появляться соответствующие `name`. И еще, Вы хотите, чтобы показывалась картинка?

Comment: в точку! только что бы поиск был по `name` а не по картинке.

Comment: не уверен, что это возможно тем способом, что Вы пытаетесь сделать... Можно, чтобы картинка появлялась после выбора из списка... но чтобы выпадающий список имел показывал картинку - не думаю, что можно

Comment: можете тогда предложить как реализовать данный механизм, что куда капать.

Comment: может поправить запрос, или еще что то

Comment: я не уверен... Вот тут в последнем примере какие-то картинки вставлены (http://salman-w.blogspot.ca/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html). Посмотрите, может быть что-то оттуда смодете реализовать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попытаюсь поправить код, чтобы данные выходили в формате jquery ui autocomplete

```
<?php
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','***','***','***') or die("Database Error");
$sql="SELECT prefix_shop.id AS id, prefix_shop.name1 AS name, prefix_images.name AS img FROM prefix_shop JOIN prefix_images ON (prefix_shop.id = prefix_images.element_id) WHERE prefix_images.module_name like 'shop' AND name like '%$my_data%'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
if($result)
{
    $rows = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {        
       $rows[] = array(
          'id' => $row['id'],
          'label' => $row['name'].'<img src="http://site.com/img/'.$row['img'].'">\n',
          'value' => $row['name'],
      );
    }
    print json_encode($rows); 
}
?>
```

Comment: передает покарябаный json =(

Comment: Смотрите как в примере сделано. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote . Возможно я чего-то не учел.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас опечатка. Не scr a src.

```
echo $row['name']."<img scr="http://site.com/img/'.$row['img'].'">\n";
```

Правильно было бы так:

```
echo $row['name']."<img src="http://site.com/img/'.$row['img'].'">\n";
```

Comment: я отпечатался в данном месте, это общую картину не исправит, мой вариант не рабочий, а приблизителен по логике.

Comment: Если это jquery ui autocomplete, то мы должны подготовить выходные данные, чтобы они правильно отображались на фронтенде.

Comment: да это оно, как правильно `подготовить выходные данные` ?